# Binding '&' method in a routed component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-components

Consider this simplified Angular 1.5.x component (all in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/um1Le4s8/2/)):

```
appModule.component('mainComponent', {
  controller: function() {
    var x = 0;
    this.broadcast = function() {
      this.onUpdate({
        count: x++
      });
    };
    this.broadcast();
  },
  bindings: {
    onUpdate: '&'
  },
  template: '<input type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.broadcast()" value="add"/>'
});
```

Html (in body)

```
<main-component on-update="this.count = count"></main-component>
Value in parent: {{count}}
```

When clicking the component button, the count variable is being update ('&' onUpdate is binded well).

Now I would like to have a route to the component from ui.router:

```
$stateProvider.state({
    name: 'state1',
    component: 'mainComponent',
    url: "#"
  });
```

Navigating to the state, results in `Cannot read property '2' of null`, removing the onUpdate member fix the error but break the binding.

What am I doing wrong? What is the way to bind callback methods of components when using ui.router route to components.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/um1Le4s8/2/)

Answer (score 0):

it looks like binding callbacks using "resolve" is not currently supported, see here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2793